# ARIMA predictions changed

Tags: python, time-series, arima

My dataset consists of a time series about the `Internet Pen Rate %` based on `GDP Growth %` and `GDP Per Capita`. I used ARIMA to predict future values for each variable and the first ones were pretty accurate for `GDP Growth %`:

```
Year    GDP Growth %
2017     8.196507
2018     6.029019
2019     3.853164
2020    -3.677511
2021     5.793255
```

```
model_gdp_growth = ARIMA(data['GDP Growth %'], order=(1, 2, 1))
model_gdp_growth_fit = model_gdp_growth.fit()
forecast_gdp_growth = model_gdp_growth_fit.forecast(steps=3)
print(forecast_gdp_growth)
```

```
GDP Growth % forecast (previous)      
2022:   2.493815 
2023:   5.267847
2024:   2.674409
```

When I tried to add the `Urbanization Rate %` feature I kinda messed up my code and got some bad results and after a review I returned to the original code, but the predictions changed for all variables. The one that changed the most was  `GDP Growth %`, the other variables were not so impacted. Also, I noticed a spike for year 2021 that wasn't there before in the plot of residual errors.

[plot of residual errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyuG4.png)

```
GDP Growth % forecast (actual)
2022:   8.203886 
2023:   17.002924
2024:   20.021371
```

I didn't change any of the data. Maybe something else happened?